Why can’t I unplug this Ethernet cable?
I can’t unplug an Ethernet cable from my laptop (ASUS Tuf Gaming F15). Looks like 2 metal pieces (in photo) holding cable lock mechanism.


Your screenshot isn’t clear enough, it’s out of focus, so What exactly is your question? Looks like a generic CAT5 Ethernet connection with a plastic locking mechanism.

this sure seems like a purely mechanical problem. I am going to assume that you are holding down the plastic clip on the cable connector to release the cable. I'd probably be using a metal probe like a jewelers screwdriver or whatever to try to identify where its getting hung up, and to push the clip down as close to the mouth of the port as I could, and try tog get it loose.

There are no metal pieces on an RJ45 other than the electrical pins themselves.

The tab to release the cable is broken off. Look at the other end of the cable to understand the mechanics then use something non-metalic preferably to carefully release it as Frank Thomas explained.

Your picture isn't super focused and is a poor angle and so does not show everything, but as others have noted the tab may be broken. A slim metal tool used gently should be able to depress the latch on the connector and release it from the port.

The tab to release the cable is broken off. Look at the other end of the cable to understand the mechanics then use something non-metalic to carefully release it.  Try to identify where it's getting hung up, and try to push the clip down as close to the mouth of the port as possible, and try to get it loose.

Your picture isn't super focused and is a poor angle and so does not show everything, but as others have noted the tab may be broken. A slim metal tool used gently should be able to depress the latch on the connector and release it from the port.
Or, if the tab isn't actually broken off and is simply obscured by the camera angle, the tab may simply be slightly bent or weakend and so is not depressing all the way. Either depress the tab as close to the laptop body as possible to mitigate the impact of the slight bend, and carefully wriggle and push/pull the connector until it releases, or use a thin metal tool to disengage it.
